# How do I set initial values upon user registration in laravel?

Tags: laravel, registration

I am trying to set a string(16) value as the User ID upon user registration. (This will not change and must be unique. It has 62^16 possibilities so I am not worried about collision at this point.)

I also want to set another random string to act as an activation code. I am having trouble with setting this when the user signs up. I have commented out the lines that are causing trouble (if these are left to run, they are inserted but all the other data is omitted).

Is this where the *setters* should go?

**User.php** (model)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {


//    public function __construct()
//    {
//        $this->attributes['mdbid'] = str_random(16);
//        $this->attributes['key'] = str_random(11);
//    }

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'mdbid';
/**
 * @var bool
 */
public $incrementing = false;

// Don't forget to fill this array
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = array('name', 'dob', 'email', 'username', 'password');

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password');

/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

/**
 * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return void
 */
public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

/**
 * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably override the save() method:

```
public function save(array $options = array())
{
    $this->mdbid = $this->mdbid ?: str_random(16);

    $this->key  = $this->key  ?: str_random(11);

    parent::save($options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i went with the latter option. The first didn't work :)